# Asincronia JavaScript en Angular con método async away

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

espero que se entienda mi duda, tengo una aplicación donde hago unas llamada a la base de datos y a la hora de utilizarlos datos recibidos me salen como undefined y creo que esto se debe a la asincronia. Me he estado informando de los Callback, Promesas y async/await y he decidido usar este último para mi aplicación pero no está funcionando y no se a que se debe.

El problema lo tengo en la funcion `main()`. Aquí os dejo el código:

```
async main(){

    console.time('measuring time');
    this.objetos = await this.cargarobjetos();
    this.itemsUser = await this.cargaritemspersonaje(this.user.nombre);
    console.timeEnd('measuring time');

    console.log(this.objetos);
    console.log(this.itemsUser);
  }
```

El método `cargarobjetos()` me devuelve todos los objetos de la base de datos y su código es el siguiente:

```
cargarobjetos(){

    this.objetosservice.getObjetos().subscribe(objects =>{
      console.log(objects);
      return objects;
    })

  }
```

Y al igual, en `cargaritemspersonaje()` hago una llamada a la base de datos que me devuelve el id de los objetos que tiene ese personaje. Aquí el código:

```
cargaritemspersonaje(nombreUser){

    this.objetosusuarioservice.getObjetos(nombreUser).subscribe(mostrar =>{
      console.log(mostrar)
      return mostrar;
    })
  }
```

El problema de esto es que pese al `async await` cuando ejecuto la aplicación sigue mostrándomelos como undefined mostrandome antes los `console.log` del main sin esperar a que terminen de ejecutarse el resto de funciones. Aquí dejo foto:
[image: imagen del error]

Comment: eso no es `async/await` estas usando observables que es un paradigma de asincronía distinto al de promesas que es `async/await` y tendrias que ver como usarlos en tu aplicación de manera adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso preferiria utilizar promesas, en lugar de los observables, para trabajar con async/await. Esto lo puedes hacer de una forma muy sencilla solo haciendo los siguientes cambios:

```
cargarobjetos(){

    return this.objetosservice.getObjetos().toPromise();

}
```

y

```
cargaritemspersonaje(nombreUser){

   return this.objetosusuarioservice.getObjetos(nombreUser).toPromise();

}
```

De esta forma deberia funcionar de la forma en que estas esperando.

Esto es asi porque async/await "modifica" las promesas para llevar el codigo subsecuente a un 'await' a como si estuviese dentro de un 'then'. De forma practica, seria lo mismo que hacer lo siguiente sin async/await:

```js
async main(){

    console.time('measuring time');
    this.cargarobjetos().then((objetos) => {
        this.objetos = objetos;
        this.cargaritemspersonaje(this.user.nombre).then((itemsUser) => {
            this.itemUser = itemUser;
            console.timeEnd('measuring time');
            console.log(this.objetos);
            console.log(this.itemsUser);
        })
    })

}
```

Pero claro, async/await da mas legibilidad al codigo.

Comment: en el `main` se puede simplificar el codigo. `this.objetos = await this.cargarobjetos();
    this.itemsUser = await this.cargaritemspersonaje(this.user.nombre);`